# SQL Server 2008 Index Multiple Columns Some not used all the time

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, indexing

I have a table with columns

```
ParameterValueId, SiteId, LocationId, ParameterId, SampleDateTime
```

and a few other columns.

`ParameterValueId` is the primary key.

I want to create an index that is not unique to speed up queries on `SiteId, LocationId, ParameterId, SampleDateTime`.

- All of my queries will use `SiteId`
- 75% of my queries will use `SiteId` and `LocationId`
- 50% of my queries will use `SiteId`, `LocationId`, and `ParameterId`
- 25% of my queries will use `SiteId`, `LocationId`, `ParamterId`, and a filter `>=/<= SampleDateTime`

Can I just create one index on `SiteId, LocationId, ParameterId, SampleDateTime`?

Or do I need to create 4 indexes?

I guess my question is if I create an index on 4 columns will it be used and still improve performance if I only use 1, 2, or 3 of those columns and not all 4?

Comment: "If I create an index 4 columns will it be used and still improve performance if I only use 1,2 or 3 of those 4 not all 4 ? "
 -- Yes. (And make sure your covering index is also in the appopriate order for your scenario( SiteId, LocationId, ParameterId, SampleDateTime). Don't think of creating an index for each column here, which is not at all a good practice in your case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a general rule-of-thumb, given the scenario you've described, one index on all four columns is probably a good starting point.  However, there may be other things you need to do to improve performance depending on the nature and shape of your data (for example, how disparate is SiteID?  Is it unique?  Does a single value account for more than 20% of the values in that colum?).

Short Answer: one covering index will be used, even if not all of the covered columns are used in the query.

Comment: I agree. I can only add: TAKE MEASUREMENTS. Before you apply any indexes, use `SET STATISTICS TIME` to capture how long your query really takes. Also capture the query plan and save that. Then you have a baseline. Then repeat with your new indexes. Now you know exactly how much of an improvement you have achieved. Also six months down the track when performance decreases you have something to measure it against.

Comment: SitedId refers to the client company location (this could be a 1 mile radus). SiteId will grow as more clients are added. So say we have 5 sites the disparterate shoud be 20%. LocationId is a specific lat,lon within the range specified by the SiteId. Each column in the index decreases in use of queries by a known fraction. Main question is when I create a index with four colmns will a query of 1,2,3 columns still use that index still used?

Comment: I'd also suggest that if you're querying the table this way most of the time then you should make it your clustered index.  If it's not your clustered index, and you're selecting other columns from the table (more than a count(*) I suppose) then you may wish to use the INCLUDE clause on your index to bring those other columns in to avoid bookmark lookups

Comment: And your question "when I create a index with four colmns will a query of 1,2,3 columns still use that index still used?"  - Yes :)